# priority queue: Using an object to compare instead of a class

Tags: c++, priority-queue

starting with `priority_queue`s, I have a problem like this: I need elements to be stored in a queue, but the criterion how they are sorted is not included in the elements itself, but somewhere different, like in a map:

```
std::map<element, value> element_values;
std::priority_queue<element> queue;
```

What I need now is something like that:

```
struct Comp
{
    std::map<...>& the_map;
    Cpmp(std::map<...> _map) : the_map(_map) {}

    bool operator() (element a, element b)
    {
        return the_map[a] < the_map[b];
    }
 }

 Comp comp(element_values);
 std::priority_queue<element, std::vector<element>, comp> queue; // does not work
 std::priority_queue<element, std::vector<element>, Comp> queue; // does work but I'd not be able to pass values to the constructor
```

The elements itself have no intrensic order. A workaround would be to define a struct wrapping this stuff up, but maybe someone knows a smarter way. I also thought about providing a compare function only valid in my current scope (which itself is a function), but as far as I know C++ does not support that, at least not with capturing local variables like I would need.

Comment: From a C++ perspective, a functor is a structure that overrides the () operator.  The code in you question is a perfectly reasonable approach to the problem.  Dietmar's answer below fills in the blanks :)

Comment: `Comp` should take the map as a const reference in the constructor, store a const reference, and the operator should be const.

Comment: I noticed that cppreference.com does not document the constructor that takes a comparison function. I wonder if that was the source of confusion.

Comment: Yes, I did not know that the constructor then takes the arguments. But here it's documented: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/priority_queue/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `std::priority_queue<T, Cont, Comp>` take the comparison object type as template argument. To pass an object referencing something, you need to pass it as constructor argument:

```
std::priority_queue<element, std::vector<element>, Comp> queue(comp);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the comparator template argument of the `priority_queue` class. Since your code has several issues, here's an overall cleaned-up version:

```
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <cassert>

typedef std::map<element, value> element_map;

struct Comp
{
    element_map const & m;

    Comp(element_map const & m_) : m(m_) { }

    bool operator()(element a, element b) const
    {
        element_map::const_iterator it1 = m.find(a), it2 = m.find(b);

        assert(it1 != m.end() && it2 != m.end());

        return it1->second < it2->second;
    }
};

typedef std::priority_queue<element, std::deque<element>, Comp> element_pq;
```

Now to use:

```
int main()
{
    element_map m;
    element_pq pq((Comp(m))); // ... sigh ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up my code, actually it's looking different than what I posted here, it was only to make the point that my functor needs arguments passed :)